# How many degrees of freedom in logistic regression?

Tags: r, regression, logistic, residuals, degrees-of-freedom

I did an experiment where 1600 people either responded (1) or not (0) to 4 treatments (400 unique people per treatment):

```
treatments <- data.frame(color = factor(c("red","blue","blue","red")), 
                         size = factor(c("small","small","big","big")), 
                         shape = factor(c("round","square","round","square")))
response <- cbind(yes =       c(30, 22, 32, 23), 
                  no  = 400 - c(30, 22, 32, 23))
```

How many degrees of freedom can I assume? R's `glm` function with `family=binomial` reports either `0` df or `1596` df, depending on how I specify the dependend variable (4x2 frequency matrix versus expanded data frame with 1600 rows):

```
## Frequency matrix: 0 df, no residuals    
summary(glm(response ~ color + size + shape, data = treatments, family = binomial()))

## Expanded data frame: 1596 df, with residuals
tab <- transform(rbind(treatments, treatments), resp = rep(c(1, 0), each = 4), Freq =  as.vector(response))  
tab <- subset(do.call("rbind", sapply(1:nrow(tab), function(i) tab[rep(i, each = tab$Freq[i]), ], simplify = FALSE)), select = -Freq)
summary(glm(resp ~ color + size + shape, data = tab, family = binomial()))
```

I'm confused. Which way is correct or how would you fit the model, e.g. to predict other treatment combinations in `unique(expand.grid(treatments))`? The one with 1596 df and residuals or the one with 0 df and no residuals? Is the experiment valid at all? Thanks for your help.

---

### Edit:

For non-R users: The output of the two summary calls (note the different residuals & df):

```
Call:
glm(formula = response ~ color + size + shape, family = binomial(), 
    data = treatments)

Deviance Residuals: 
[1]  0  0  0  0

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept) -2.44235    0.18430 -13.252   <2e-16 ***
colorred    -0.01143    0.20263  -0.056   0.9550    
sizesmall   -0.05853    0.20263  -0.289   0.7727    
shapesquare -0.34298    0.20263  -1.693   0.0905 .  
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

(Dispersion parameter for binomial family taken to be 1)

    Null deviance: 2.9995e+00  on 3  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance: 5.4179e-14  on 0  degrees of freedom
AIC: 28.194

Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 3
```

and

```
Call:
glm(formula = resp ~ color + size + shape, family = binomial(), 
    data = tab)

Deviance Residuals: 
    Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max  
-0.4084  -0.3949  -0.3442  -0.3364   2.4085  

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept) -2.44235    0.18430 -13.252   <2e-16 ***
colorred    -0.01143    0.20263  -0.056   0.9550    
sizesmall   -0.05853    0.20263  -0.289   0.7727    
shapesquare -0.34298    0.20263  -1.693   0.0905 .  
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

(Dispersion parameter for binomial family taken to be 1)

    Null deviance: 785.53  on 1599  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance: 782.53  on 1596  degrees of freedom
AIC: 790.53

Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 5
```

Comment: Were the same people in multiple treatments? What are your factors? I'm trying to make sense of your setup.

Comment: Your first formulation of the `glm` call appears to be incorrect, as the data frame "treatments" does not include a variable called "response". It's usually most straightforward to have a data frame with one row per observation for this type of analysis. For the analysis based on one row per observation, do you still have a question? As @gung pointed out, it would be easiest to help if we knew what all the factors are, rather than the general `resp ~ .`

Comment: @gung It's a web test with 1600 unique people. (However good that you ask. I also had another setup in mind, where each individual could respond to up to three times, not just one time. In that case, it would have been 1600*3 responses, but not from unique people anymore. Would that violate any assumptions? Maybe another question.) The factors represent certain webpage test elements (let's say A is color "blue" vs "red", B is text size "big" vs "small"). It's a fractional factorial design to calculate the main effects. In the end, I want to estimate the response rates for all 8 combinations.

Comment: @EdM I thought the matrix should be possible, too, according to the help on [`?family`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/family.html) (No 3 under details). It confused me that both yield different results. The third possibility (`weight` parameter) is similar to the matrix result.

Comment: @EdM "do you still have a question?" - the question is more or less what's the right way to report such an experiment and to predict the success of the other 4 possible treatment combinations. Both models yield different results in terms of degrees and freedom and error. I have no statistical or mathematical background, just Andy Fields book, it's difficult to tame the stats jungle.

Comment: @gung I edited the question to maybe make it a bit catchier.

Comment: It'd help also to show the output from the `summary` functions - not everyone uses R. A hint is that when you consider how you're going to *use* degrees of freedom, & likelihoods, you shouldn't find any differences between the two ways of specifying the model.

Comment: @Scortchi Thanks, I added the output. Indeed, e.g. `with(fit, 1 - pchisq(null.deviance-deviance, df.null-df.residual))` is the same. But besides asking myself, which of the 2 ways is the right one to report the result, I was also wondering, if the modelling is valid at all, since there are no residuals. Someone pointed me to the fact that it's not possible to estimate 4 values (intercept + 3 covariates) with just 4 observations. However, since there are no NAs, it seems to be ok for the main effects, But maybe the are underlying problems like not beeing able to judge on the test statistics?

Comment: Thanks, that's very helpful. Brief answer is that both formulations are equivalent - look at the coefficient estimates & standard errors. But I have to go ...

Comment: **This question is purely an `R` misunderstanding:** your output with zero residuals is based on passing a dataset with only four observations to the code!

Comment: @whuber: I see it as reflecting a more general puzzlement about the relation between modelling at the contingency table level versus that of individual observations.

Comment: Thanks for your comments! My reporting take-aways would be: (1) I got 1596 df, one would prefer a data frame against a contigency table, but reporting 0 df would would be fine, too, because estimates & errors are - except for the model residual - the same. (2) Although the experimatal design is only pairwise complete (e.g. I no data for red+small+round) & there're more 0 than 1, I could rely on the test stats (e.g. just small model chi, only shape has p<0.1). (3) It's legit to predict the response for all combinations using `predict(fit, newdata = unique(expand.grid(treatments)), "response")`